# Check if row has specific childs on join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I want to make a SQL to get the user which name is `Mark` and are the author of the posts with ids `1` and `3`.

NOTE: It is unknown how many posts I need to check for. So it might need to generate that part of the SQL query using PHP.

How can that be done?

Users Table:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Mark     |
|  2 | John Doe |
+----+----------+
```

Posts Table

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id |    text     |  author_id  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | First Post  |           1 |
|  2 | Second Post |           2 |
|  3 | Last Post   |           1 |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

This is just a sample case of use, not real data.

NOTE: I know how to check if user is author on one post, but not multiple in the same row. So basicly that is what I need help with, I guess it must be a `left join`.

For making the check for the user named `Mark` and check if he is author for post id `1` I do the following:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts
    ON users.id = posts.author_id
WHERE
    users.name = 'Mark'
    &&
    posts.author_id` = 1
```

Comment: you're doing an inner join. you'd only ever get `posts` where Mark was the author, meaning the `posts.author_id` test in your `where` clause is redundant - it was already performed at the `join` level.

Comment: I see, it was a bad example. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just selected the `id` from `users`. If you need more columns then just add it to the `select` and the `group by` clause.

```
SELECT users.id
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.author_id
WHERE users.name = 'Mark'
AND posts.author_id in (1,3)
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING count(distinct posts.author_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-query to find only users with both 1 and 3:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
WHERE users.name = 'Mark'
  and 2 = (select count(distinct posts.id)
           where users.id = posts.author_id
             and posts.id IN (1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT users.name, posts.posts, posts.authorid
FROM users INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.authorid where posts.authorid = 1

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. :) Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HAVING` clause to achieve desired outcome:

```
SELECT users.name
  FROM users
    INNER JOIN posts
        on users.id = posts.author_id
 WHERE users.name = 'Mark'
 GROUP BY users.name
 HAVING COUNT(posts.author_id) > 1
```